# IEnumerable Error on View with Partial Load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am trying to create a view in my application that performs basic CRUD commands in ASP.NET Core to teach myself some new skills. I am however stuck and would appreciate some assistance please.

I would like to have each "component" of the application sitting in a partial view for maintenance going forward. I **initially** had my Index view use a declaration of type IEnumerable (for the for each loop):

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Web.Models.Sample.SampleModel>
```

Which worked perfect for returning the list and rendering the page but then when trying to have my Modal window partially loaded into the page and insert data using the "CreateSample" function on the controller it was not picking up the function and failed the insert (no form action found). If I then try to add:

```
@model Project.Web.Models.Sample.SampleModel
```

to the CreateModal view page it throws an error and wont even let me render the page, I presume because its being partial loaded the app is seen as having two SampleModel declarations. If I create this page completely separate and not partially loaded with the normal @model declaration it works.

I have the basic setup going so far and have included my code for each below.

**Model - SampleModel**

```
public class SampleModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SampleText { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller - SampleController**

```
public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        public const string ControllerName = "Sample";
        //Open Database Connection
        private _DBContext DBDatabase = new _DBContext ();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Model = DBDatabase.Sample.Select(s => new SampleModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                SampleText = s.SampleText
            }).ToList();

            return PartialView(Model);
        }

        [ActionName("_CreateModal")]
        public ActionResult InsertNewRecord()
        {
            var Model = DBDatabase.Sample.Select(s => new SampleModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                SampleText = s.SampleText
            }).ToList();

            return PartialView("_CreateModal", Model);
        }
```

**Views - Index, View, Create**

*Index* - Calls Partial Views for View and Create

```
@using Project.Web.Controllers
@model Project.Web.Models.Sample.SampleModel
<!--html stuff here -->
@await Html.PartialAsync("_CreateModal")
<!--more html stuff here -->
@await Html.PartialAsync("_ViewData")
```

*View* - Foreach to Loop Records

```
@model Project.Web.Models.Sample.SampleModel

<table style="width: 100%;" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Sample Text</th>
            <th class="text-center">Status</th>
            <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var sample in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@sample.Id</th>
                <td>@sample.SampleText</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="badge badge-success">Active</div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div role="group" class="btn-group-sm btn-group">
                        <button class="btn-shadow btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                        <button class="btn-shadow btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Create* - Insert New Record

```
@model Project.Web.Models.Sample.SampleModel

<form method="post" asp-action="/SampleModel/CreateSample">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="CreationTime">SampleText</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SampleText" name="SampleText" placeholder="SampleText">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Your `Create partial view` expects its model to be of type `SampleModel`, but you're passing it a `List<SampleModel>`

Comment: Thansk Ammar, I have solved that issue now by creating a standard list for the SampleModal. The issue with having too @model declarations is now still persisting. 

public ActionResult _CreateModal() { return View(); }

Comment: You need to pass an empty model in action to create view and the view needs a declaration too.Besides, your view loops the Model but it is not a List which will also causes an error.We are able to pass model directly to [partial views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2#access-data-from-partial-views) like `@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName", model)`

Comment: Thank you all. 

I landed up making another model and passing that model to the new partial view as mentioned above. This resolved my issues :)

Answer (score 2):

As per Ammar's comment, you've just copy-pasted the Index Controller's data access. When building a form allowing the user to create a single new item, then the pattern is to typically pre-instantiate an empty model and pass it to the view:

```
[ActionName("_CreateModal")]
public ActionResult InsertNewRecord()
{
    var model = new SampleModel(); // If Id is a GUID, then you could assign one here

    return PartialView("_CreateModal", model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stuart. Silly me didnt pick that up. I have made the adjustment per your and Ammar's responses. Does this mean that my CreateModal window will still need an @model/controller deceleration to reach that function in the controller?

If I add the @model declaration to the Modal window that pops up then the site renders an error.